# What is the meaning of this phrase?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Can anyone rewrite this phrase in an easier fashion, so I can understand it:

> The last function of reason is to recognize that there is an infinity of things which are beyond it. It is but feeble if it does not see so far as to know this.
>
> *—Blaise Pascal*

Comment: Could you explain what you do not understand?

Comment: the second sentence is the more difficult one and I don't get it:  "It is but feeble if it does not see so far as to know this."

Comment: "Reason is only feeble if reason does not see far enough to understand this". **But**  here = only. An old usage.

Comment: what about does not see far enough? 
it's a metaphor or what?

Comment: I think it would mean the same thing in your language. Reason cannot see far enough. yes, reason is like a person.

Comment: I think the **1st part** can be rephrased in this way: The last usage of "reason" is acknowledging that there are so many things which happen out of its reach/intervention/ability. And the **2nd part**: The "reason" is considered weak if it fails to have cognizance/awareness to know that fact (fact: the real existence of things beyond it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last part,

> It is but feeble if it does not see so far as to know *this*.

could be rephrased as:

> Reason is weak if it not does realize that *there is an infinity of things which are beyond it*.

---

By the way, if you find the original [French sentence](http://inters.org/pascal-faith-reason-wager) and use [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=fr&tl=en&text=La%20derni%C3%A8re%20d%C3%A9marche%20de%20la%20raison%20est%20de%20reconna%C3%AEtre%20qu'il%20y%20a%20une%20infinit%C3%A9%20de%20choses%20qui%20la%20surpassent%3B%20elle%20n'est%20que%20faible%2C%20si%20elle%20ne%20va%20jusqu'%C3%A0%20conna%C3%AEtre%20cela.), the result is easy to understand and, surprisingly, pretty accurate (you just need to change *she* to *it*).

> The last step of reason is to recognize that there is an infinity of things that surpass it; [it] is only weak, if [it] does not go so far as to know that.